# MVC 4 Razor _Layout.cshtml use a HTML section for only one page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a scenario where I want specific content from _Layout.cshtml to be used for only one view

**"_Layout.cshtml"** looks like this..

```
<div>
    //common part for all pages - 1
</div>

<div>
   //only for index page - want this only for index page.
   //but don't know how to specify this condition. if(it is an index page) then use this section
   //I can't move this section to my index page, 
   //because I have some html content Displayed on Index page from below section, i.e. common part-2.
</div>

<div>
    //common part for all pages - 2
</div>

  @RenderBody()

 <div>
     //common part for all pages - 3
</div>
```

My **index.cshtml** page should look like this..

```
<div>
    //common part for all pages - 1
</div>

<div>
    //only for index page
</div>

<div>
    //common part for all pages - 2
</div>

  //Content specific to index.cshtml

 <div>
     //common part for all pages - 3
</div>
```

And all other pages should look like this..

```
<div>
    //common part for all pages - 1
</div>

<div>
    //common part for all pages - 2
</div>

  //Content specific to all other pages

 <div>
     //common part for all pages - 3
</div>
```

How should I do it? what should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can make a non mandatory section in your master page

```
@RenderSection("sectionforindex", required : false)
```

and in your index page implement it

```
@section sectionforindex
{
<div>
    //only for index page
</div>
}
```