# View specific css in Razor Pages with _Layout.cshtml

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a `_Layout.cshtml` file with a `<head>` section that looks like so:

```
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have a View called `Index.cshtml` (that is using `_Layout.cshtml` as a layout) with a `<head>` section that looks like so:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Home/Index.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Now this line in `Index.cshtml` is styling my DataTables correctly, but it is messing up my layout page even though it is located in the `Index.cshtml` and not the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I must be getting a bit messed up with how my css is working throughout my web app. I have tried using `@section` but I couldn't get that to work either.

So my question is how can I make the css in `Index.cshtml` only apply to that page rather than also affecting the css in `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Have you tried removing that line from the `Index` page because it is already in the `Layout`?

Comment: You misunderstand what a layout file is doing I think. If you look at your output now you will have two `head` elements. You need to put all the head lines in the layout.

Comment: or how HTML works @DavidG ...

Comment: @DavidG so is there no way to render a specific css for one page or do they have to be in every page?

Comment: See the answer below, but I really would recommend have Bootstrap in the shared file across all pages.

Comment: @DavidG I've been writing full html pages for all of my razor pages a well as layout so seems I have misunderstood whats required here. Will go back to some tutorials

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC 4 Razor \_Layout.cshtml use a HTML section for only one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181550/mvc-4-razor-layout-cshtml-use-a-html-section-for-only-one-page)

Answer (score 2):

In your `_Layout.cshtml` use the `RenderSection` method with the required argument set to false:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    ....
    @RenderSection("head",false)
</head>
```

Then in your view that requires additional css:

```
@section head {      
  <link href="my_view_specific_css.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
}
```